# How to include a full HTML file with specific styles inside a div

Tags: angularjs, preview

I'm making a script to preview email templates so I'm getting a full HTML page (with ) and I'm willing to make a popup with this page.
I'm getting the result from an API that gave me the full code inside a variable.
How to display this page inside my app without surcharging the styles ?
Thank you

Ps: I can't use an iframe since I can't get the preview from a simple get query (without header)

Comment: Put it in an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of these options (all of them have drawbacks)

1. [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) (AngualrJS directive) - doesn't provide styles encapsulation
2. [iFrame](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/ZZp3Cv) - provides styles encapsulation, browser compatibility is not a problem. Still, you may need to set up or adjust your CSP policies if you are worried about security or have it already in place.
3. [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) - provides styles encapsulation, but you need to make sure it fits your supported browsers, and it's quite tricky to implement for AngularJS

UPD: based on your recent update, I guess you can proceed with `ng-bind-html` directive (HTML content will be sanitized, but you will have to cope with styles intersection and head & body tags warnings). If it doesn't work - try iFrame based on the approach referenced above (you don't need to make any external queries/requests for that).

Comment: Thanks managed to do it unsing ng-bind-html and $sce.trustAsHtml(myVar)

Answer (score 0):

iframe is the tag which you can use for call other html pages into your web page

```
 <iframe src="http://www.page.com" name="targetframe" allowTransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" >
        </iframe>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention this. But I can't get my preview from a simple query